# End of life PHP 7.0 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, php, lts

The end of life of PHP 7.0 is planned for December 3, 2018 but Ubuntu's support for version 16.04 LTS ends in 2021.

The question is, what happens to PHP 7.0 from December? Does Canonical assume updates until 2021? If a security bug is discovered, for example in 2019, does it remain unpatched?

Thank you very much.